# HashMap of WeakReferences for passing data between activities

Tags: android, communication, hashmap, weak-references

I am particulary interested in the following suggestion from the [official android FAQ](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html).

> **A HashMap of WeakReferences to Objects**
>
> You can also use a HashMap of WeakReferences to Objects with Long keys. When an activity wants to pass an object to another activity, it simply puts the object in the map and sends the key (which is a unique Long based on a counter or time stamp) to the recipient activity via intent extras. The recipient activity retrieves the object using this key.`

I haven't found a way how to properly implement this. And I'm not sure why WeakReferences are preferred here and why not use hard references.

My implementation (I would like to send an instance of **class XY** from the **activity A** to the **service B**):

- the receiving service has a static HashMap of Objects.

  ```
  public static HashMap<Long, Object> parameters = new HashMap<Long, Object>();
  ```
- code for the sending part (activity A)

  ```
  long key = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
  B.parameters.put(key, new XY());
  Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
  i.putExtra("PARAM_UPLOAD", key);
  startService(i);
  ```
- code for the receiving part (service B)

  ```
  long key = intent.getLongExtra("PARAM_UPLOAD", -1);
  XY data = (XY)parameters.get(key);
  ```

The code is using hard references. Why should I use weak references here (as proposed by the FAQ)? And is such a use pattern for passing data ok or do you prefer something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why should I use weak references here (as proposed by the FAQ)?

Because you are leaking memory. Anything you put in that static `HashMap` is never garbage-collected.

> And is such a use pattern for passing data ok or do you prefer something else.

I prefer only passing simple data between activities. Anything that isn't a primitive (or a system-supplied `Parcelable`, like a `PendingIntent`) should be considered part of the data model and should be managed as such. [Here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/08/decoupled-activities.html) where I go into more details.

Comment: Tnx. So what would be the preferred way for passing an array of custom type objects from an activity to a service (the array of data is passed to the service as from there it is uploaded to an online server).

Comment: @humus: Just as objects. Bind to the service with `bindService()`, and you can define whatever API you want. Here is a sample project that uses a service to provide a bridge to a Web service, passing a `Location` to the service and returning an `ArrayList<Forecast>`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherAPI/

Comment: @CommonsWare "never garbage-collected" - unless we do it manually in the launched Activity, when ending it, or immediately after acquiring the data.
Is there anything wrong with such an approach, compared to reliance on automatic collection (disregarding, for now, the near-necessity to manually recycle Bitmaps, if we pass them)?
I also have concerns about the availability of weak-referenced data to the launched Activity.
While it will (is that guaranteed, though?) be available on initial launch, it won't on the Activity's recreation (onCreate(notNull)) after destruction while not visible.