# Android - How to pass HashMap<String,String> between activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, hashmap

How to pass the `detail` HashMap to another Activity?

```
HashMap<String,String> detail = new HashMap<String, String>();
detail.add("name","paresh");
detail.add("surname","mayani");
detail.add("phone","99999");
......
......
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154744/hashmap-of-weakreferences-for-passing-data-between-activities this will help you. And in another way make your HashMap as public and static, set its values in caller activity and use its values into called activity. And before adding values to your HashMap, clear its previous values.

Comment: @pankaj i am not getting anything from the above link code

Comment: @Tanmay please don't change the OP's code. Add a comment or answer outlining the change instead. (Rejected edit)

Comment: @Pekka No problem.I just wanted to make sure the right thing

Comment: Can you prefer to make your hashMap as public static? I can explain it.

Comment: @PM- Paresh Mayani: This might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another I dont found any direct method to do this instead of creating `static HashMap`

Comment: @Vikas i already know that how do we pass values, arraylist , object from one activity to another, but i dont know this only. Thanx

Comment: @PM Paresh Mayani: As per your question, I really don't think you need to pass the `HashMap` instead simply your can do this by putting an `ArrayList<String>` in intent and on the other activity you can obtain the value form those positions , assuming that you know which data is stored at the perticular position.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is pretty simple, All `Collections` objects implement `Serializable` (sp?) `interface` which means they can be passed as Extras inside `Intent`

Use `putExtra(String key, Serializable obj)` to insert the `HashMap` and on the other `Activity` use `getIntent().getSerializableExtra(String key)`, You will need to Cast the return value as a `HashMap` though.

Comment: Excause me. What if I can have a HaspMap<String, Object>? Can it be serialize? The value Objects are just int, String or float type. No custom Object type.

Comment: Keep in mind, that the map will not be serialized. It will be parcelized by internals if possible. And then you will get a HashMap on the other side, despite you've put LinkedHashMap or any other map.

Comment: "You will need to Cast the return value" -- that's what I was missing.

Comment: I'm getting "Unchecked cast" warning

Comment: The "Unchecked cast" warning is basically saying "you're on your own" ;)

Answer (score 67):

### Solution:

**Sender Activity:**

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap= adapter.getItem(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("hashMap", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receiver Activity:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();    
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

Comment: Hey hi, I am getting parcel error at runtime. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value` I am passing HaspMap<String, JSONArray>

Comment: @anish bcz JSONArray is not serializable.

Comment: Thanks mate, though it is a late reply, appreciated your help. :) @Abubakar

Answer (score 4):

i used this to pass my HashMap

```
startActivity(new Intent(currentClass.this,toOpenClass.class).putExtra("hashMapKey", HashMapVariable));
```

and on the receiving activity write

```
HashMap<String,String> hm = (HashMap<String,String>) getIntent().getExtras().get("hashMapKey");
```

cuz i know my hashmap contains string as value.

Comment: Are you sure that you are able to get HashMap<String, String> using getExtras.get("key") ?

Comment: yeah...as long as you passed "HashMap<String,String>" to the receiving activity

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is if the information is something that might be considered "global" to the application, to then use the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. You simply extend it and then define your custom class in your manifest using the <application> tag. Use this sparingly, though. The urge to abuse it is high.

Comment: thanx for the support, and "new" information , but i just need to pass HashMap between two activities i.e. From activity A to activity B

Comment: I figured. Just wanted to offer it as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am showing sample code for your reference. I just tried this code, it works fine for me. Check this :

MainActivity :

```
    final HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    hashMap.put(1, "Hi");

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("h", hashMap);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

SecondActivity :

```
Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,"Hi " +  getIntent().getSerializableExtra("h").toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```