# How to send data back to Parent Activity for Hashmap in android?

Tags: android

I am sending data in hashmap back to parent activity from child acitvity

here is my code
Child activity

```
    private void sendDataToPrevPg(HashMap<String, String> hm) {     
    // Send to previous activity page
    Bundle bndle = new Bundle();
    bndle.putSerializable("stockList", (Serializable) hm);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("stkList",bndle);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);           
    this.finish();      
}
```

In parent

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {         
        if (data.hasExtra("stkList")) {             

            Bundle wrapper = getIntent().getBundleExtra("stkList");
            HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>) wrapper.getSerializable("stkList");
            System.out.println("...serialized data4.."+myClass3);
        }
    }
}
```

showing error at line

```
 HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>)       wrapper.getSerializable("stkList");
```

Logcat::
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

how to send data in hashmap? to parent activity

Comment: Check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992097/android-how-to-pass-hashmapstring-string-between-activities

Comment: its not an issue of serealize just strore data to common class and use it and remove from that

Comment: @user3811114 thnks but still thr is null in logger sysout statement

Comment: See below, added sample code for your reference.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just simply missed the key "stkList" when you retrieved the HashMap from the bundle. It should be "stockList" instead.

Change this:

```
HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>) wrapper.getSerializable("stkList");
```

to this:

```
HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>) wrapper.getSerializable("stockList");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void sendDataToPrevPg(HashMap<String, String> hm) {     
      // Send to previous activity page
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     intent.putExtra("stkList",bndle);
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);           
     this.finish();      
    }
```

In parent Activity You can Receive HashMap value  :

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {         
    if (data.hasExtra("stkList")) {                      
        HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>) data.getSerializable("stkList");
        System.out.println("...serialized data4.."+myClass3);
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am showing sample code for your reference. I just tried this code, it works fine for me. Check this :

MainActivity :

```
    final HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    hashMap.put(1, "Hi");

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("h", hashMap);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

SecondActivity :

Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,                                                                                                                       "Hi " +  getIntent().getSerializableExtra("h").toString(),            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {         
        if (data.hasExtra("stkList")) {             
            Bundle wrapper = getIntent().getBundleExtra("stkList");
            HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>) wrapper.getSerializable("stockList");
            System.out.println("...serialized data4.."+myClass3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the wrong key. Change the error line to

```
HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>) wrapper.getSerializable("stockList");
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in this line of code

```
HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>) wrapper.getSerializable("stkList");
```

it should be stockList instead of stkList as below

```
HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>) wrapper.getSerializable("stockList");
```

Comment: I done that but problem is still thr and list is not empty i check at child acitivity

Comment: do you mean you are still getting NullPointerException at above line of code even after changing the string key from stkList to stockList?

Comment: can you pl try data.getBundleExtra("stkList") instead of getIntent().getBundleExtra("stkList") then in next line check if (wrapper!=null) then go in next lines else print the toast. it seems the wrapper (bundle) itself is null.

Comment: wrapper is not null bcz i checked for null condition its working fine

Comment: Got it...Workig now Bundle wrapper = data.getBundleExtra("stkList"); HashMap<String, String> myClass3 = (HashMap<String, String>)wrapper.getSerializable("stockList");

Comment: just edit your question with comments what changes you did and got it working so can help others in case they come up to this page.

Answer (score 0):

used data instead getIntent()

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {         
        if (data.hasExtra("stkList")) {                             
            Bundle wrapper = data.getBundleExtra("stkList");----data instead getIntent()
            if(wrapper!=null){
                HashMap<String, String> stockDtls = (HashMap<String, String>)wrapper.getSerializable("stockList");
            }
        }

    }
}
```