# HashMap passed to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, tablerow

I'm trying to pass an `HashMap` object to another activity using getter `tableRow.getRowData()` as shown in code below:

```
tableRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ToDoDetailActivity.class);
                putExtras(newIntent, tableRow.getRowData());//<---
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }
        });
```

Actually `tableRow` object belong to a custom class that inherits from TableRow which inside an `HashMap<String, String> rowData` that represents the entire row (key: 'DB column', value: 'DB field value'). As I said, `rowData` is returned by `getRowData()`.

Is this a good way to transfer object within `putExtras()`?

Also, seeing [this Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#ReceiveIntent), I can't figure how to deal with `rowData` to the other activity.

EDIT:
My question is a bit different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992097/android-how-to-pass-hashmapstring-string-between-activities) because it's not possible to pass, even if HashMap class is serialized by default, hash map object through `putExtra()` (I've tryed to do so by previously seen that question).

Comment: I think there is no issue by passing data with this way. But there are many other ways also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How to pass HashMap<String,String> between activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992097/android-how-to-pass-hashmapstring-string-between-activities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that, as kind Kingfisher Phuoc said, ther's no way to pass `HashMap` through Activities, unless calling `putExtra()` for each element of the `HashMap`. I think that's the simplest solution ever.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no way to pass `HashMap` through `Activity`. If you really need to pass all `HashMap` data, I recommend to use `Application` to store your `HashMap` then you can access your `HashMap` data from everywhere in Application.

Comment: It's probably one solution but I don't think that's a good idea provide that as global variable. I'll try another way calling much `putExtra("key", "value")` many time as the number of HashMap's record.

Comment: @AndreaGrimandi yes, it's not a good solution (but not bad of course). However, you should consider it if you need pass a lot of data to another activity. If your data is big when passing, It will make your app force stop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the standard way, but you only can pass Serializable objects as extras. `HashMap` and `String` implement `Serializable`, so it should work.

It migth be useful to have a look to that `TableRow` inheriting class, but I'll try to guess some code to send:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ToDoDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("tableRow", tableRow.getRowData());//<---
startActivity(newIntent);
```

And to get TableRow data from within the receiving `Activity`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)intent.getSerializableExtra("tableRow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `getRowData`. all that you must do is :

```
HashMap<Object, Object> extraData = new HashMap<>();
putExtras("myHashMap", extraData);
```

and in your second activity:

```
(HashMap<Object, Object>) intent.getSerializableExtra(YourFirstActivity.EXTRA_DATA);
```