# Passing values from activity A to B and from B to C and so on in android

Tags: android, android-intent, hashmap

The problem i've stuck is 
I have 4 activities namely A, B ,C and D . the flow is first A then B then C and so on.
I want to pass data of A to B and then data A+B to C , then data of A+B+C to D and so on..
I've used in Activity A Intent of `Hashmap`

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>(); //declared Globally
hashMap.put("key", value);
i.putExtra("map", hashMap); (i is the Intent Object)
startActivity(i); //Starting the Intent
```

And on receiving side i.e Activity B

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)i.getSerializableExtra("map");
```

Here i'm able to get Successfully the data , but when i try to pass on foward this data to next activity i get null values causing `NullPointerException`.
In the B activity

```
Hashmap<String,String> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>;
hashMap2.put("key",hashMap.get("key"));
Log.i("Value:",hashMap.get("key"));
```

Here i get the values successfully put when same way i pass `hashmap2` to C activity i get `NullPointerException`. 
Not understanding what's wrong in here.

**I want to pass the values and not store them so i'm preferring Intents over Shared Preferences.**

Thanks for your help .I've found out why it was giving me null values
1)In B activity I was doing the wrong way to get the values i.e first getIntent and then sum of A+B values i.e putExtra should be used only when I declare the new intent for the C class. As i was first doing putExtra and then new Intent to C , so in C i used to get Null Values.

Comment: you can use shared preferences instead of passing values from One activity to another.

Comment: Better use SharedPrefrence

Comment: why you have tagged [tag:javascript]?

Comment: I did not add javascript , dont know why its showing.

Comment: It's hard to know without the code for setting & getting the map (for B->C) and knowing the line of code where it crashes. More to the point, why put a map as an extra? Bundles are essentially maps, so why not simply put your key/value pairs in there and pass the whole Bundle along?

Comment: post your stack trace for the exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to pass HashMap<String,String> between activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992097/android-how-to-pass-hashmapstring-string-between-activities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.You can simply send values like this and it will work.

In Activity A:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("key1","value1");
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity B:

```
String value1=getIntent.getStringExtra("key1");
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityC.class);
intent.putExtra("key1",value1);
intent.putExtra("key2","value2");
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity C:

```
  String value1=getIntent.getStringExtra("key1");
  String value2=getIntent.getStringExtra("key2");
  Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityD.class);
  intent.putExtra("key1",value1);
  intent.putExtra("key2",value2);
  intent.putExtra("key3","value3");
  startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity D,

```
String value1=getIntent.getStringExtra("key1");
String value2=getIntent.getStringExtra("key2");
String value3=getIntent.getStringExtra("key3");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is really hectic to send value from one activity to another using Intent same code written in every activity but alternative way is to use cache

```
 public class CacheManager {
        public static Map<String, Object> cachedData = new HashMap<>();


        public static void clearCache() {
            cachedData.clear();

        }

        public static void putIntoCache(String key, Object value) {
            CacheManager.cachedData.put(key, value);
        }

        public static Object getFromCache(String key) {
            if (cachedData.containsKey(key)) {
                return CacheManager.cachedData.get(key);
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

One of the advantage of this approch is you can modify data where ever you want and put modified  data in cache again

step 1-  Create class called cacheManager

Step 2-  from anywhere you can put value  into Cache HashMap

step 3-  from anywhere you can get Value From Cache

**Enjoy !**

Comment: Is using of a static cache really the right approach? - there are other approaches which are more object oriented

Comment: yes it is !! in these approch you can access data anywhere in application and also allow you to modify where ever you want !! its easy to impliment and understand and less confusing ............................just think on it

Comment: what do you mean by object oriented this is also object oriented .......i am not able to understand what you want to say

Comment: instead i would use a DI Framework like Dagger2 and create a Singleton ... but yeah who knows :) its a matter of style

Comment: as per your requirement you can change that !!  have a great day

Comment: This is a convenient way to share members, but it is *not* a cache. It is a map that pins memory for the (executing) lifetime of your app. It will only ever grow and never evicts stale values.

Answer (score 0):

use intent.putExtra in intent like this.

```
   Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
   String strName = null;
   i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
   startActivity(i);/
```

and retrieve .

```
     String newString;
     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    newString= null;
} else {
    newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
}
       } else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Option**

Store data in application context

Declare a class that should extend Application

```
public class HashTableBundle extends Application {

    private Hashtable<String,String> mHashTable  = null;

    public Hashtable<String, String> getmHashTable() {
        return mHashTable;
    }

    public void setmHashTable(Hashtable<String, String> mHashTable) {
        this.mHashTable = mHashTable;
    }
}
```

You can set data into application context by

```
HashTableBundle mStat = (HashTableBundle) getApplicationContext();
mStat.setmHashTable(mMainHashTable);
```

You can get it from any activity by using

```
HashTableBundle mStat = (HashTableBundle) getApplicationContext();
 Hashtable<String,String> mHashTable = mStat. getmHashTable();
```

You need to add `HashTableBundle` in `AndroidManifest` otherwise application Throws class cast exception

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".HashTableBundle"> . . . </application>
```

**Second option**

```
MainActivity.java



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Hashtable<String,String> mMainHashTable = new Hashtable<>();
     MHashBundle mm = new MHashBundle();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMainHashTable.put("hai","I am From MainActivity");
        mm.setmHashTable(mMainHashTable);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ClassB.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("myhashtable", mm);
        System.out.println("data Main Activity :"+mMainHashTable.get("hai"));
        startActivity(mIntent);
        this.finish();


    }
}
```

Hashtable container `MHashBundle.java`

```
public class MHashBundle implements Serializable {
    private Hashtable<String,String> mHashTable  = null;

    public Hashtable<String, String> getmHashTable() {
        return mHashTable;
    }

    public void setmHashTable(Hashtable<String, String> mHashTable) {
        this.mHashTable = mHashTable;
    }
}
```

note `MHashBundle.java` must implement `Serializable`

Second Activity ClassB.java

```
public class ClassB extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(ClassB.this,ClassC.class);
        MHashBundle mBundle = (MHashBundle) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myhashtable");
        mIntent.putExtra("myhashtable",mBundle);
        System.out.println("data class B :"+mBundle.getmHashTable().get("hai"));
        startActivity(mIntent);
        this.finish();
    }
```

Thrird Activity

```
public class ClassC extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            MHashBundle mBundle = (MHashBundle) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myhashtable");

        System.out.println("data class C :"+mBundle.getmHashTable().get("hai"));

    }
}
```