# How to parse data from one Activity to another activity as long as the HashMap is using intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, hashmap

i'm trying to parse data from one Activity to the Other.
The data which i would like to parse are from the following HashMap:

```
  ImageButton map = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mapbtn);
        map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent i = new Intent(Locations.this, MapsActivity.class);
                for (final HashMap<String, String> contact : contactList) {
                    String names = contact.get("name");
                    String str = contact.get("street");
                    String post = contact.get("postalcode");
                    String open = contact.get("opening");
                    String entr = contact.get("entry");
                    String age = contact.get("agegroup");
                    String bag = contact.get("background");
                    String prevbild = contact.get("imageurl");
                    String fsk = contact.get("Fsk");
                    i.putExtra("name", names);
                    i.putExtra("postal", post);
                    i.putExtra("street", str);
                    i.putExtra("opening", open);
                    i.putExtra("entry", entr);
                    i.putExtra("agegroup", age);
                    i.putExtra("background", bag);
                    i.putExtra("imageurl", prevbild);
                    i.putExtra("fsk", fsk);

                }
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

This is working fine, but i dont know how i can get the data at the other activity. I tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
for (final HashMap<String, String> contact : contactList) {
        String names = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),names, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you try logging the variable `names` in the first activity to make sure it's not an empty string?

Comment: FYI: you can chain multiple `putExtra` calls together like: `i.putExtra("name", names).putExtra("postal", post).putExtra(. . .`

Comment: try putting them in a bundle, also every iteration in the loop will override the value associated with the given key, so even if you passed the map 
correctly you will only receive the last one in the other activity

Comment: Possible duplicate question. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992465/1827254

Comment: Btw why do you use an HashMap and not a List of object Contact?

Comment: @Eric O'Connel, i logged it and its working

Comment: I am using a Hashmap to get the Data from my Json into my App

Comment: The reason why i would like to parse the data from one to the other activity is that i would like to get the Coordinates from the one Activity and show the coordinates in a map in the other activity