# Can't pass Hashmap with intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass Hashmap to another intent but I get error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<String,android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo>
```

Code:

```
Map<String, ApplicationInfo> map = returnedMap;
Intent i = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, DisplayClass.class);
i.putExtra("total",total);
i.putExtra("map", map);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11155142/5293286 look in this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Intent.putExtra` only accepts primitive type / `Parcelable`, `Serializable` object.

Since you're holding a `Map`, it's pretty easy to send it as `HashMap` because `HashMap` implements `Serializable` interface.

```
// If your originial Map is not a HashMap, you have to convert it
// HashMap<String, ApplicationInfo> map = new HashMap<>(returnedMap);
// If it's already an HashMap, you have to cast it
// HashMap<String, ApplicationInfo> map = (HashMap)returnedMap;
i.putExtra("map", map);
```

And in the receiver side:

```
HashMap<String, ApplicationInfo> map = (HashMap<>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map")
```

Answer (score 0):

As HashMaps serialize and Maps don't, so try doing the below segment because you are using using the

> Intent.putExtra(String, **Serializable**) method:

```
HashMap<String, ApplicationInfo> hashMap = returnedMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `HashMap` cause `HashMap` is the class which implements `Serializable`. And `Map` is a parent `interface` of `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<String, ApplicationInfo> map = returnedMap;
Intent i = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, DisplayClass.class);
i.putExtra("total",total);
i.putExtra("map", map);
startActivity(i);
```