# How to send Map<String, List<String>> through a intent

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Can anyone help me to send a `hashmap` through a intent and receive it on the other activity first parameter is strings and 2nd parameter is a list of strings cant find anyone that is struggling or trying to send this through a intent the way that i am trying too

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new hashmap<>();
```

Comment: you can use serializeable  for this purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to pass HashMap<String,String> between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992097/android-how-to-pass-hashmapstring-string-between-activities)

Comment: Kunu sending a HashMap<String, String> is different than sending a HashMap<String, List<String>>

AliAhmed Thank you good sir your answer did work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use Serializable and pass the map through intent.
Code Example of Data Sender is as follows :

```
Map map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

List<String> l1 = new ArrayList();

l1.add("HEllo");
l1.add("John");
l1.add("Michael");
l1.add("Jessy");

map.put("Names" , l1);

Intent intent = new Intent("CurrentActivityName".this, "DestinationActivityName".class);

intent.putExtra("Map",(Serializable) map);

startActivity(intent);
```

Code for Receiver:

```
Map map = new HashMap<String,List>();
map = (Map) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Map");
```

Now you can access the data using variable named **map**.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a Model Class that implements *Serializable***

```
public class DataWrapper implements Serializable {
   private Map map;

   public DataWrapper(Map dataMap) {
      this.map= dataMap;
   }

   public Map getData() {
       return this.map;
   }

}
```

**For Fragment**

```
    Fragmentt recent = new Fragmentt();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Map m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put("data", data);
    bundle.putSerializable("Data", new DataWrapper(m));
    recent.setArguments(bundle);
```

**Receive Data on Next Fragment**

```
        DataWrapper dataWrapper = (DataWrapper) bundle.getSerializable("Data");
        map = dataWrapper.getData();
```

**For Activity**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
        Map map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Data", data);
        intent.putExtra("Data", new DataWrapper(map));
        startActivity(intent);
```

**Receive Data on Next Activity**

```
        Map map;
        DataWrapper dataWrapper = (DataWrapper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Data");
        map = dataWrapper.getData();
```